# Desktop apps or web services to test receiving text / SMS messages US-based

Tags: tools

I'm a manual QA tester.

I have a client (web-based) which allows certain business to send custom promotional text messages to their customers provided the business account has the customer's mobile phone number.

I've used services such as TextNow, which is a mobile phone / tablet app, that gives you (in this case, the "customer") a US-based mobile phone number for which the "customer" can send & receive text messages to other mobile numbers. This app uses an Internet connection as opposed to a cellular plan or service.

I'm looking for similar software that I can use on my PC. Why am I not using it on my iPad or iPhone? Both are... broken... over the course of the years.

- Needs to be a US-based mobile phone number (most of the ones I've found are International numbers).
- Needs to be either (a) a PC / desktop application, or (b) a web-based application that I can use on my PC.... not a tablet or smartphone app.
- Needs to be able to receive the test text / SMS messages. I don't need voice (neither outgoing nor incoming) nor do I even need to be able to send text / SMS messages from this mobile number or application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know which protocol you need to use? It's probably SMPP, CIMD or UCP/EMI.

Answer (score 2):

I would (and do) use Google Voice, which allows you to send and receive text messages from within a browser. http://voice.google.com/ You will get a US phone number.

Answer (score 2):

I've used textfree on my computer, and ipod. Its free, and supplies a US phone number.  I believe it fits all of your requirements nicely.  As a bonus, the service is quite nice for personal use as well.

Web:
http://www.pinger.com/textfree/

To use from an ipod/iphone if anyone else is looking

App Store:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/text-free-textfree-real-phone/id399355755?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

We use SMS with [Mailosaur](https://mailosaur.com). You get a US or UK number and when an application sends a message to it you can view the message in the web application.

(We use it for email as well, which is the main use case for our testing and it's great!)